# Como resolver: You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de login, porém esse erro esta me prendendo e não achei respostas ate agora:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
  to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
  near '�rios WHERE login = 'admin'' at line 1
```

Vou colocar o trecho do código para ajudar nos conselhos:

```
if(empty($login) or empty($senha)):
        $erros[] = "<li> O campo login/senha precisa ser preenchido </li>";
    else:
        $sql = "SELECT login FROM usuários WHERE login = '$login'";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connect)); //mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die mysql_error();

        if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0):
            $senha = md5($senha);
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuários WHERE login = '$login' AND senha = '$senha'";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

                if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 1):
                    $dados = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
                    $_SESSION['logado'] = true;
                    $_SESSION['id_usuário'] = $dados['id'];
                    header('Location: home.php');
                else:
                    $erros[] = "<li> Usuário e senha incorretos </li>";
                endif;


        else: 
            $erros[] = "<li> Usuário inexistente </li>";
        endif;
```

Comment: Sua tabela se chama `usuários`, com acento mesmo? Se sim, verifique as codificações dos arquivos e banco de dados.

Comment: sim, no banco de dados está salvo com o acento, e em todas as partes do codigo que faço referencia á ele eu acrescento o acento também, faz 1 hora que estou pesquisando e não acho nada :/

Comment: Pode colocar o código completo? Aparentemente a mensagem está mostrando que o erro está na linha 1 (at line 1).

Comment: vou colocar, pode ser no comentario mesmo ? mas a linha 1 é a abertura do php e depois tem um require_once

Comment: <?php
//Conexão
require_once 'db_connect.php';


//Sessão
session_start();


//Botão enviar/Send button
if(isset($_POST['btn-entrar'])):
 $erros = array();
 $login = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['login']);
 $senha = mysqli_escape_string($connect, $_POST['senha']);

Comment: esse é o inicio do codigo (linha 1 ate linha 14)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usa prepared statments, dessa forma a tua query é vulneravel.

O teu erro provavelmente está na query pois estás a usar um acento em "usuários" !

De qualquer das formas usa as prepared statments tens ai o exemplo do codigo e o link do site da documentação:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Código:

```
if(empty($login) or empty($senha)):
    $erros[] = "<li> O campo login/senha precisa ser preenchido </li>";
else:
    $sql = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT login FROM usuarios WHERE login=");

    $sql->bind_param("s", $login);

    $sql->execute();

    $resultado = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($connect)); //mysqli_query($connect, $sql) or die mysql_error();

    if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0):
        $senha = md5($senha);
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE login = '$login' AND senha = '$senha'";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);

            if(mysqli_num_rows($resultado) == 1):
                $dados = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado);
                $_SESSION['logado'] = true;
                $_SESSION['id_usuário'] = $dados['id'];
                header('Location: home.php');
            else:
                $erros[] = "<li> Usuário e senha incorretos </li>";
            endif;


    else: 
        $erros[] = "<li> Usuário inexistente </li>";
    endif;
```